# Run an API multiple times and store the result in an array

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs-observables

I want to run an API call multiple times and then store the API response in an array/observable.

```js
public getProgramNamesList() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.totalPages; i++) {                     
 
 this.accountAdminApiService.getAccountAdminProgramsBySearch((i)).subscribe((programResults: ProgramSearchResults) => {
                if (programResults?.data?.length) {
                    this.totalPages = Math.ceil(programResults.totalCount / this.pageSize);

                    this.programResults$.next(programResults.data);
                }
            });
        }

        return this.programResults$;
    }
```

I tried the above code. It is only returning the first set of results and the API is not running multiple times.

Comment: You could either use `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` - depending on when you need each values. Or, in a much cleaner way - if you also have the BE code, just create a proper API that will return some data based on a range (0, totalPages).

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I don't have the access to the BE code and I can't modify the API. Something has to be done from the FE code. How can I use combineLatest in this particular scenario?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do actually sync options in the loop - instead, you should convert multiple async actions to a single one and subscribe to the result. If I understand you situation correctly, here is [a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-w3fmrq?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) of one of the approaches

```
const api$ = (i: number) => of(i).pipe(delay(100));
const results$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);

function getProgramNamesList() {
  forkJoin(
    Array.from({ length: 100 }, (_, i) => i).map((i) => api$(i))
  ).subscribe(results$);
}
results$.subscribe(console.log);
// Open the console in the bottom right to see results.

getProgramNamesList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I've no idea how you're using `programResults$` there could be two ways of doing that:

*Doing some logic for each calls :*

```
public yourFunction() {
    const idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, "test", "somethingElse"];
    from(idList)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((id) => this.http.get(`https://api.agify.io/?name=${id}`))
      )
      .subscribe(
        (character) => {
          // This will be triggered every time an http gets resolved.
          this.programResults$.next(programResults.data);
        }
      );
  }
```

*Doing some logic at the end, when all the calls are done and the data is already retrieved:*

```
public yourFunction() {
    const arrayCalls = [];
    for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
      arrayCalls.push(this.http.get(`https://api.agify.io/?name=${i}`));
    }

    forkJoin(arrayCalls).subscribe(data => {
      // data is an array of results.
      // This is called just once
      this.programResults$.next(data)
    })
  }
```

You can checkout the live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-zqqbnc?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This worked for me Jacopo Sciampi. I was able to update this according to my requirement. Thanks a lot.